# Change svg image color to be gradient

Tags: html, css

change this color [image] --> to this [image]

I have to change the color of circle to be gradient

```
<div class="loader loader--style3" title="2">
  <svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="#070e1a" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is clear enough on the tutorial that @Harry posted before but I update your code here with the styles applied.

Just add a definition of your linear gradient and after make reference on the `fill` property of your circle.

I do not know what are exactly the colours that you want to use so just change `darkblue` and `lightblue` of the linear gradient definition to your custom colours.

```html
<div class="loader loader--style3" title="2">
  <svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
        <linearGradient id="customGradient">
            <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#123354"/> 
            <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#070f1c"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    
  <path fill="url(#customGradient)" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i need this but it's circle is half i want it in full circle as 2 image looks

Comment: @Anubhavpun But here the `linear-gradient` is in all the circle. You can change the values of `offset` to get a bigger colour than the other.

Comment: yes i change the offset but circle is not full it's is 1/3 circle i need full

Comment: @Anubhavpun Do you have the colours that are displayed on the image? To try with them.

Comment: the color is   <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="#123354"/> <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#070f1c"/> but i need the circle full not be half as shown

Comment: @Anubhavpun Look it now. I think it is covering the full circle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112983/discussion-between-anubhav-pun-and-error404).